# Hebrew Latex - VSCode

Tags: miktex, overleaf, hebrew, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode to write a `.tex` files. 
I've downloaded MikTeX to get latex on my computer. 
I'm trying to add a Hebrew text to the file and got a bunch of errors. 
I tried to download the culmus-miktex, but it didn't work.

Is there a way to write Hebrew in latex with VSCode? 
If so, please guide me step by step how to do so.

PS, The code I ran is a code that worked good in Overleaf website. 
How can I run a latex code with VSCode the same way Overleaf does?

Edit: This is the code I ran on Overleaf -

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}
\selectlanguage{hebrew}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2.5cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\title{כותרת של מסמך}
\author{המחבר}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \section{זוהי הכותרת בעברית}
    זוהי הפסקה בעברית \\
    גם אם אני ארשום את כל הדבר בעברית, זה יראה נהדר
    \subsection{תת פסקה}
    \subsubsection{תת של תת פסקה}
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:visc}
    \tau = \mu \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
    \end{equation}
    \selectlanguage{english}
    \section{English}
    From here and on, the text is in English
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:visc}
    \tau = \mu \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Since you say this worked for you on Overleaf, please add a small compilable code example showing what worked there.  That will give potential helpers the exact information they will need to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, I add my code, but my question is how I write Hebrew latex with VSCode in general.